# Why fault address is 0x00000006 for SIGSEGV on 32bits ARM platform?

Tags: c++, c, assembly

I met a SEGV_MAPERR crash in my program.

```
pid: 934, tid: 934, name: Binder_1  >>> system_server <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000006
backtrace:
    #00  pc 00000006  <unknown>
    #01  pc 00006925  /system/lib/libcutils.so (set_sched_policy+136)
    #02  pc ffffffff  <unknown>
```

I can understand the fault address is 0x00000000 or 0x00000004 or something others. For example, invalid class virtual base pointer, or invalid/wild function pointer.

But I can not understand the 0x00000006 as a fault address. Was the stack modifed illegally? But nearby the wrong code, neither the return statement, nor jump instrument were found.

Is there any other potential reason? Thank you very much!

Comment: `struct { int i; short s; char c; } *p = NULL; printf("%c", p->c);`

Comment: @H2CO3 - This might need to be a packed structure, but this is certainly a plausible explanation.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to note that my program was compiled by alignment of 4 bytes.

Comment: @DevboardFan it doesn't appear the crash is in your code at all, so how you compiled it may not be an issue here. I think H2CO3 is definitely on the right track here.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, thank you very much. This is an android application. And the whole android system is compiled by me. I'm sure that the compile option is 4 bytes-alignment for all used libraries.

Comment: I'm not the most familiar with android, but in my experience, things like `__attribute__((packed))` override what your default alignment is, due to the fact that they are, well, packed. If you're not packing a packed structure, then you have an issue. Is it possible for you to re-compile the libraries with some debug symbols enabled, so that you could see the full stack trace?

Comment: If a function wrote a 6 to the position on the stack where its return address was stored (array overrun or similar) and then executed a return, I guess that would explain it.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, the backtrace is very strange. You can see the top invokation is pc@0xffffffff. So I guess the stack was destroied.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: Why should it need to be packed? If `int` is 4 bytes and `short` is 2 bytes, I'd expect the `char c` member to be at an offset of 6 bytes.

Comment: @KeithThompson - yes, of course you are absolutely right.  My incorrect comment was based on the assumption that the compiler would 32bit align all struct members, regardless of their size.  When I think about this I realize this is incorrect.  I think the correct assumption to make is that the compiler will not place struct members to straddle 32bit aligned boundaries, unless the packed attribute is used.  But I think the general point is that we cannot directly infer from code how the compiler will place struct members, without somehow checking the compiled object.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see why you find it strange. This would be is a typical outcome of attempting to access memory location at offset `6` through a null pointer. For example, if you have `char *string` and access `string[6]` when `string` happens to be a null pointer, you will typically get segfault at address `6`. Access `string[7]` and get a segfault at address `7` (Wow! This one is not even even!!!) That way you can access absolutely arbitrary address and get a segfault on it.

(The pedantic stuff: ... assuming that null pointer is represented by zero address and that `char` matches the machine byte)

If the segfault was caused by control transfer to address `6`, then there could be many different reasons for it. For example, a call was performed through an invalid function pointer that somehow acquired value `6` (an uninitialized pointer, a pointer damaged by a buffer overrun nearby). Alternatively, stack location that stores the return address from a function could have been damaged by a buffer overrun and acquired value `6`, which caused control transfer to address 6 at function return. And so on and so forth.

You yourself mention "invalid/wild function pointer" as a possible reason. But why do you find it surprising then that the control got transferred to address `6`? An invalid pointer can acquire an arbitrary value, not necessarily aligned on 4-byte or 8-byte boundary.

Comment: You can see the address 0x06 is not accessed by data region. It is accessed by code region. I mean if you access string at 0x06, the register PC will not be set to 0x06.